# Syncing UI Canvas to Photon Network | PunRPC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have an issue where I cannot sync UI Canvas information to PhotonNetwork. It syncs just fine without Photon, and I get correct information when I debug it. But if i start it with photon, it does not sync.

Code below:

```
void Start()
{
    PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    Debug.Log("I know who is :  " + PV);
}



 void Update()
{

    PV.RPC("DisplayHP", RpcTarget.All);
    DisplayHP();

    ShootTest();
    Debug.Log("Player HP : " + playerHP);

}


}
[PunRPC]
void DisplayHP()
{
  if(PV.IsMine)
    {
        showHP.text = playerHP.ToString();
    }      
         
}
```

}

possibly I am using it in wrong way, can someone please shed some lights what I am doing wrong in here? This is just an example from Health Canvas, other canvas also acting exactly same as health canvas.

Full script below :

```
[SerializeField] float playerHP = 100f;
[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI showHP;  
[SerializeField] AudioClip audioClip;


public int armorCheck;
public int energyCheck;
float energyBack = 25;
//public PhotonView PV;


void Start()
{
   // PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    
}

public void EnergyPot()
{
    //if(PV.IsMine)
    //{
        Ammo currentAmmo = GetComponent<Ammo>();
        int energyCheck = GetComponent<Ammo>().GetCurrentAmmo(AmmoType.EnergyDrink);

        if (energyCheck > 0)
        {
            playerHP = energyBack + playerHP;
            if (playerHP >= 100)
            {
                playerHP = 100;
                currentAmmo.ReduceCurrentAmmo(AmmoType.EnergyDrink);

            }
        }
    //}                
}
public void TakeDamage(float damage)
{
 //   if (PV.IsMine)
 //{ 
        Ammo currentAmmo = GetComponent<Ammo>();
    int armorCheck = GetComponent<Ammo>().GetCurrentAmmo(AmmoType.Armor);
    if (armorCheck <= 0)
    {
        playerHP -= damage;
        if (playerHP <= 0)
        {
            GetComponent<DeathHandler>().HandleDeath();
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(audioClip, Camera.main.transform.position);
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Dead_Player");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentAmmo.ReduceCurrentAmmo(AmmoType.Armor);
    }
  }
//}
//public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
//{
//    if(stream.IsWriting)
//    {
//        //DisplayHP();
//        stream.SendNext(playerHP);
//    }
//    else if (stream.IsReading)
//    {
//        //DisplayHP();
//        playerHP = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
//    }

//}

 void Update()
{                
    DisplayHP();
    ShootTest();        
}

void ShootTest()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Shoot_Player", true);
        // GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("ShootPlayer");
    }
   // GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Shoot_Player", false);
}

void DisplayHP()
{
    //if(PV.IsMine)
    //{
        showHP.text = playerHP.ToString();            
        //Debug.Log("PV works under DisplayHP, code  :  " + PV);
        Debug.Log("Player HP : " + playerHP);
    //}            
             
}
```

}

Comment: anyone please?? :'( I desperately need help on this

Comment: What exactly do you need to sync? You need all players to have same amount of HP showing, or do you need some kind of list of all players HPs?
Anyway, you are not sending any information in RPC, you only sending command to call a method. And don't call RPC in `Update()`, this creates too much traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You are only syncing a parameter less method call which updates a display .. **but** your are never updating the information to display: `playerHP`

[`PhotonView.RPC`](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent#remote_procedure_calls) takes the method name, `RpcTarget` and then optionally as many parameters as you like / your method expects.

```
void Start()
{
    PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    Debug.Log("I know who is :  " + PV);
}

private void Update()
{
    if(PV.IsMine)
    {
        ShootTest();
        Debug.Log("Player HP : " + playerHP);
    }
}

// only executed every 0.2 seconds to reduce traffic
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(PV.IsMine)
    {
        // pass in the value to sync
        PV.RPC(nameof(DisplayHP), RpcTarget.Others, playerHP);
        DisplayHP(playerHP);
    }
}

[PunRPC]
void DisplayHP(float hp)
{
    // receive the synced value if needed 
    playerHP = hp;
    showHP.text = hp.ToString();
}
```

---

Actually to avoid more redundant network traffic you should use a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) which automatically updates the display whenever it is changed and only sends the remote call whenever the `playerHP` actually changes like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private float _playerHP;

private float playerHP
{
    get => _playerHP;
    set
    {
        _playerHP = value;
        showHP.text = playerHP.ToString();

        if(PV.IsMine)
        {
            // sync the change to others
            PV.RPC(nameof(RemoteSetHP), RpcTarget.Others, _playerHP);      
        }
    }
}

[PunRPC]
void RemoteSetHP(float hp)
{
    // this executes the setter on all remote players
    // and thus automatically also updates the display
    playerHP = hp;
}
```

so whenever you set

```
playerHP = XY;
```

it automatically updates the display and if it is your photon view it sends the remote call to others and also update the value and display there.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to my comment, here is an example. Let's assume you have `Text` for your HP and for other player HP. First, you change your HP by calling `UpdateHP` method, you update `Text` for your HP and send RPC to others, that updates otherHp on their clients (because you will be 'other' on their machines) with your new value for your HP.

```
public Text myHpText;
public Text otherHpText;

void UpdateHp(int hp)
{
    myHpText.text = hp.ToString();

    PV.RPC("UpdateOtherText", RpcTarget.Others, myHp);
}

[PunRPC]
void UpdateOtherText(int hp)
{
    otherHpText.text = hp.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I have one prefab called "Player" and in a lobby we have total of 4 players. all those players will use same UI Canvas and scripts, so somehow i would need to seperate them.

For instance: if player1 has 90hp, player2 should not see 90hp on his ui canvas.

Comment: Then you don't need anything related to photon at all, don't call rpc and don't check pv.isMine,just update text with your HP

Comment: at the beginning it was without rpc and pv.ismine, however it simply did not work when i instantiate with Photon, that is why I thought i need to pass this information through photon. It still works without photon so not quite sure how to troubleshoot this issue :/

Comment: Yeah, just tried again. I Instantiate the player with Photon, when i debug player's HP it shows correct information on console, however in UI it does not

Comment: What do you instantiate with photon? Player or UI? Seems like it is a reference to HP amount problem. Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: I added full script on my post if you are interested.
I instantiate Player, I do not do anything in UI via Photon at the moment